There is an error while creating dynamic mockresponse while using groovy script. Content is not allowed in prolog.]
I am using Soap UI 5.7.0, i'm new in scripting. below script is failing with error ERROR:An error occurred \[Failed to dispatch using script; org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Content is not allowed in prolog.\], see error log for details What to do to resolve it.
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.lang.Binding;

import groovy.lang.Script;
def requestBody="";
try {
    while ((line = mockRequest.getrequestContent().getReader().readLine()) != null)
    {
        requestBody = requestBody+line;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.info(e)
}
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(mockRequest.requestContext);
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(requestBody);
def CCNumReq = holder.getNodeValue("//cardNumber");
requestContext.ccnum = CCNumReq

Expecting return value as one of the tag value from request xml.

so, requestBody has incorrect xml. post in your question the value of requestBody variable before the getXmlHolder call.
